# SQL query to find out if different rows with same 2nd columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a MessageThread table

```
UserUid   ThreadUid
===================
K1    111
N1    111
K1    222
K1    333
N1    444
R1    111
R1    222
D1    333
E1    444
T1    555
```

One threadUid is only used for a same group of users.

K1 and N1 can on only have same ThreadUid.

if I know UserUid: K1 and N1

How can I know if K1 and N1 has a same ThreadUid?

Is there a way to get ThreadUid based on the provided UserUid? Seems impossible...

### ------------

If the UserUid is K1 and N1
Result will be 111

If the UserUid is K1 and T1
Result will be empty

If the UserUid is N1 and E1
Result will be 444

Comment: Example results would help-- hard to say what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find threads that both users have in common:

```
select  mt1.ThreadUid
,       count(*) as ThreadCount
,       (
        select  count(distinct mt3.UserUid) 
        from    MessageThread mt3 
        where   mt1.ThreadUid = mt1.ThreadUid
        ) as UsersInThread
from    MessageThread mt1
join    MessageThread mt2
on      mt1.ThreadUid = mt2.ThreadUid
where   mt1.UserUid = 'K1'
        and mt2.UserUid = 'N1'
group by
        mt1.ThreadUid
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60df4/4)

Comment: OP wants to know which rows with UserID=K1/N1 don't have the same ThreadID which seem to be not allowed.

Comment: If I also need the total count as another col, what should I do?

Comment: @tianxu0836: You could use `group by` instead of `distinct`, added to answer

Comment: but it won't get this result:ThreadUid - 111; ThreadCount - 3. The count should be total users in this thread uid

Comment: @tianxu0836: Query for total users added to answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @ThreadUid = ThreadUid 
    FROM Users
    WHERE UserUid= @UserUid1 and ThreadUid=(Select ThreadUid From Users Where UserUid=@UserUid2)
```

Will return null if it is not the same and will return the actual ThreadUid if both K1 and N1 has the same ThreadUid

Answer (score 0):

This might work (**This is not Tested**): -

```
SELECT ms1.UserUid, ms1.ThreadUid, ms2.UserUid, ms2.ThreadUid 
FROM MessageThread ms1, MessageThread ms2
WHERE ms1.ThreadUid <> ms2.ThreadUid AND
ms1.UserUid = 'K1' AND ms2.UserUid = 'N1'
```

This will give you all the Records, which have different `ThreadUid` for `UserID = K1` and `UserID = N1`

Seems like this might give you `duplicate` record. Please check it and revert. I don't have `sql-server` installed so can't test it.

**Or better, you can return records with same `ThreadUid`**: -

```
SELECT ms1.UserUid, distinct ms1.ThreadUid, ms2.UserUid, ms2.ThreadUid 
FROM MessageThread ms1, MessageThread ms2
WHERE ms1.ThreadUid = ms2.ThreadUid AND
ms1.UserUid = 'K1' AND ms2.UserUid = 'N1'
```